# How to debug issues regarding peering?

Tags: debugging

My cloud and local instance use the same file, my local host has telnet access to 30333 on the cloud instance, I've made sure to connect with the correct peerId, I can still see no peers form. How can I enable debug messages regards to peering ?

Comment: Set env `RUST_LOG=trace` to get a lot of messages (First thing to check is that you're getting network traffic in the standard output messages.)

Comment: See for lots of ways you can filter for specific areas: https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding:

```
--log sub-libp2p=trace
```

Should let you see all the trace logs related specifically to libp2p and networking.